# Unexpected error in Project Center

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, project-server, pwa

Suddenly, when opening project center in SharePoint 2013 a message appeared

> "Unexpected error"

And nothing found in the log.

Comment: Nothing found in the event viewer, or the ULS logs? did you check on all servers or run `Merge-SPLogFile`?

Comment: first check event viewer, second check what's the latest project you have published and try to publish it again and make sure that you have entered all fields in correct format? maybe also you have changed some fields in the default list of project site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unexpected error or unknown error in project center is an ambiguous error that should be traced based on each scenario by checking the Event Viewer and trace log. so please check the below investigation steps:

**Investigation Steps**

**First**, I suggest editing all views in project center to be filtered with the project published date to be less than the date before the problem occurred by following:

- Open PWA Settings > Look and Feel > Manage Views.
- Below Project Center views > edit all views with a custom filter.
- The project published date to be less than the date before the problem occurred.
- This does not solve the issue, but it allows the project center to open without error and show all projects else the projects that were published and might cause this issue.

Most of the cases refer to an error occurred in project information that you recently published. so try to trace the latest projects you have published and open it with Microsoft project and check the resources and basic information and try to publish it again.

**Second**, Check the Event Viewer to get the root cause of the issue.I wrote an article before related to this issue but as I told you it differ based on each scenario, so please check it at [AN UNKNOWN ERROR HAS OCCURRED INSIDE PROJECT CENTER IN PROJECT SERVER](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/02/14/exception-message-was-cannot-insert-duplicate-key-row-in-object-dbo-usermemberships-with-unique-index-cx_usermemberships_recordid_membergroupid_sid-the-statement-has-been-terminated/) may be it the same case.

Comment: Take your time, Hope it help you :)